# Spring Web App show user headers

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, user-agent

I am trying to show users information i browser when they open the web application. I`ve made some basic web app. I suppose that i made a mistake in the controller class and do not print the header in browser. The application works correctle. I package the war file with maven and deploy it to Tomcat where it opens correctly the .jsp file but do not show my headers. I will copy the controller here and hope that someone will help me to fix it.

Best regards !

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class SiteController {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/headers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getDomain() {

        ModelAndView modelandView = new ModelAndView("Headers");

        modelandView.addObject("user-agent", getUserAgent());
        modelandView.addObject("headers", getHeadersInfo());

        return modelandView;

    }

    private String getUserAgent() {
        return request.getHeader("user-agent");
    }

    public Map<String, String> getHeadersInfo() {

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
            String value = request.getHeader(key);
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your JSP look like?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch

It is very simpe .jsp file. There is just one header:

<h1>Some text here</h1>

Comment: @Nikola: In case your JSP just contains the `h1` tag, it will never show the Spring model. Please show the JSP.

Answer (score 1):

You should not autowire an HttpServletRequest like this. It has to be *renewed* on every **request**, but Spring controllers are by default singletons (a single controller of every class). Pass the request to any of your methods (will be injected automatically):

```
public ModelAndView getDomain(HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Than pass the current request to your private methods:

```
...
modelandView.addObject("user-agent", getUserAgent(request))
...

private String getUserAgent(HttpServletRequest request) {
...
```

The other option you have is to put your controller into prototype scope (@Scope("prototype")). But that would mean every call to your app would create a new contoller. Better keep them stateless and singleton.

Your JSP is just static... You need to read the values "user-agent" and "headers" from the **model**:

```
...
<h1>Show Headers of current user</h1>
<%= request.getAttribute("user-agent"); %>
...
```

**Update**

Add the UAD libs to your WEB-INF/libs directory. Change the "getUserAgentMethod" like this:

```
private ReadableUserAgent getUserAgent(HttpServletRequest request) {
   UserAgentStringParser parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getResourceModuleParser();
   return parser.parse(request.getHeader("User-Agent"));;
}
```

Comment: I have this result - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36. Now i use Chrome. How can i show just what browser i`m using without the other stuff ?

Comment: You need to parse the String in your controller, or use [this library](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/) in your controller and just return the "browser", not the whole "user-agent"

Comment: I added all jars from the link but when i replace my method with yours i gives me a lot of mistakes ?

Answer (score 1):

The headers are not going to appear by magic. Use JSTL tags to output the data:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Show Headers of current user</h1>

<c:forEach var="entry" items="${headers}">
  Key: <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>
  Value: <c:out value="${entry.value}"/>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Elliott Frisch
This is my .jsp file. I hope it`s good ?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Show Headers of current user</h1>
</body>
</html>
```